# IF Conditions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve FIZZ BUZZ(3 factors[3,5,7]) question in R programming with only basic functions(not using any libraries). I want to understand how to print TRUE STATEMENTS if:

1. Only 1 condition is true
2. If either of the 2 conditions is true - Print both TRUE statements.

The coding must be minimal. I used nested IF-ELSE statements and the code is so long.

```
     ' factors <- c(3,5,7)
res <- c("Pling", "Plang", "Plong")
fizzbuzz <- function(number, factors){
  mod <- c(number %% factors ==0)
 ifelse(mod[i], res[i], number){
 }
fizzbuzz(105,factors)'
```

Thanks!!

Comment: If you're trying to learn R programming, then I suggest asking us to give you the answer is not going to help you the most. Can you post the code you've tried and we can help you improve *that* code?

Comment: @r2evans The above code only helps me to print TRUE statements of only one conditions. What I am trying to achieve is - If  conditions 1&2 | 2&3 | 1&3 are true, would the output show concatenated print statements? On the contrary if only 1 condition is true, print the relevant statement.

Comment: Code like that doesn't do well in comments, can you please [edit] your question and add that to a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: some hints. (1) `&&` is the AND operator (2) if you want to execute multiple expressions in response to an if-block, you should wrap them in curly brackets (e.g `if (a && b) { print("foo1"); print("foo2") }` (semicolon only needed if you want to include both expressions in the same physical line of code, i.e. no line breaks)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks!! So logic is: if a number is divisible of **a** - print foo1, divisible by **b** - print foo2, divisible by **c** - print foo3 and if divisible for **a&b** - print foo1foo2, if divisible by **a&c** - print foo1foo3 and if divisible by **b&c** - print foo2foo3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach:

```
factors <- c(3, 5, 7)
fizzbuzz <- function(num, factors) {
    MOD <- num %% factors == 0
    if (any(MOD)) {
        cat("Factor(s) are", paste0(paste(factors[MOD], collapse=", "), "."))
    } else cat(paste0(factors, collapse=", "), "are not factors.")
}
fizzbuzz(105, factors)
# Factor(s) are 3, 5, 7.
fizzbuzz(104, factors)
# 3, 5, 7 are not factors.
fizzbuzz(165, factors)
# Factor(s) are 3, 5.
```

Comment: I have edited the code(please refer to code in the initial post) I tried after your suggestion, but the ifelse is not acknowledging multiple conditions. Kindly can you look into it.

Comment: You do not need `ifelse()` and you should not use it in a loop.